# Efficiently checking if a string contains a set of words

Tags: java

Say I have a number of sets of words such as: (water, flour, eggs) and (beans, water, milk)

If a user enters a string that contains all those words in any order, a message is displayed. Such as "I have eggs water and some flour" -> "That makes a cake".

What is the most efficient way to accomplish this, assuming there may be a large number of word set and message combinations to check, for each string the user enters.

My initial idea is to use .contains:

```
for(each-word-set)
{
  i = word-set.length;
  for(each-word)
  {
    if(string.contains(word))
    {
       j++
    }
  }
  if(i == j)
  {
     //Yes this string contains all words.
  }
}
```

Is there a better method than this?

Comment: Look into aho-corasick.

Comment: I'm not sure yet I guess hashmap?

Comment: Does the string the user enter have any kind of delimiters? Like flour,Beans etc ?

Comment: Spaces between each word would act as delimiters.

Comment: You should consider `if(string.contains(word)){j++}else{break;}` ... Leaves the loop if goal unreachable. As a consequence you can evict the test `i==j`. If you reach this point its always ok.

Answer (score 2):

My initial way: 
Using the space as a delimiter.

We can do the following.

### Steps

Create a List. As follows

1) Use Java split function. To create array.

```
 List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(string.split(" ")))`;
```

2) Create a Hash Map.

```
Map<String, String> hash = new HashMap<String, String>();    
for(i = 0 ; i < list.length(); i++)
{
   hash.put(list[i], list[i]);
}
```

Where the `list[i]` is going to be your key.

3) Retrieve matches.

Now when the user enters a word you are interested in, you can use the containsKey
  command. For example

```
  if (hash.containsKey("flour") && hash.containsKey("water") && hash.containsKey("beans");

  println("Whatever you want");
```

The thing to note is creating a HashTable is useful for big data sets. Here is a [link](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/2008/08/supercharging-your-hashmaps.html), you should see to see the benefits. Retrieving data from a Hash Table is O(1), so virtually instantaneous.

Hopefully that was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To exdend my comment. There have been some more errors. My final solution so far would be:

```
public class Someclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] words = { "water", "flour", "eggs", "beans", "water", "milk" };
        String[] testStrings = { "water flour eggs beans water milk", "somewhat else",
                        "wader flour ekks beans water milk" };
        for (String string : testStrings) {
            boolean found = true;
            for (String word : words) {
                if (!string.contains(word)) {
                    found = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (found) {
                System.out.println(string + " - That makes a cake");
            } else {
                System.out.println(string + " - That makes no cake");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can first create an array or list of strings splitted by space as:

List<string>userStr= userEntry.split(" ");

Now use extended for loop within another loop as:

for(String s: userStr)
{
    for(String d: yourList){
       if(s.equals d){
          //your code 
           break;
        }
     }
}
```